# Figuring out a code snippet .[x,y] in public R code

Tags: r, dplyr

I am replicating a method for imputing migration data with publicly available code, but my own data. I have encountered a problem in the following code snippet (nested inside a loop, with i set to 1 in this example):

```
# set up possible combinations
d5 <- expand_grid(year0 = 2010:2020, 
                  sex = c("male", "female"),
                  age = c("0-4", "05-11", "12-17", "18-59", "60+")) %>%
  mutate(e = vector(mode = "list", length = n()))

# pull out available vector of countries for this iteration of the loop
cc <- d3 %>% 
    mutate(alpha3 = as.character(alpha3)) %>%
    filter(year == d5$year0[1], 
           sex == d5$sex[1],
           age == d5$age[1]) %>%
    drop_na() %>% 
    pull(alpha3)

# create the wanted variable
s1 <- d0 %>% 
    filter(year == d5$year0[1],
           sex == d5$sex[1],
           age == d5$age[1],
           pob %in% cc,
           por %in% cc) %>%
    xtabs(formula = stock ~ pob + por) %>%
    .[cc,cc]
```

The only thing I do not understand is what the .[cc,cc] right at the end does. It looks like it is accessing the lower and right most cell in the created table, but this doesn't make sense in that context. Not understanding the command is a problem, as when I run the code, I get a subscript out of bounds error. If I change the command to [,cc], it produces a table that is almost what I'm looking for, but lacks one entry and that destroys the dimension of my matrices further down.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. What does the command do?
2. Can it be an artefact of "pob %in% cc" and "por %in% cc" - the two dimensions of the table - having different lengths?

Edit: My presumption in 2. seems to have been correct. In that iteration, cc has length 94, but pob %in% cc only 93. Therefore, I get the out of bounds. The solution needed would need to basically only make the table so that I access the common elements in por and pob. I tried to filter for pob %in% por and the other way round, but that did not work. I still don't get what the command does anyway.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

For reference, these are the objects in question:

d3 is a tibble of the availability of different metrics for a given country-year-gender-age combination:

```
name        alpha3  year sex    age   pop   demog por   pob   fb_gt_zero
  <chr>       <fct>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     
1 Afghanistan AFG     2000 male   0-4   AFG   AFG   NA    NA    NA        
2 Afghanistan AFG     2000 male   05-11 AFG   AFG   NA    NA    NA        
3 Afghanistan AFG     2000 male   12-17 AFG   AFG   NA    NA    NA        
4 Afghanistan AFG     2000 male   18-59 AFG   AFG   NA    NA    NA        
5 Afghanistan AFG     2000 male   60+   AFG   AFG   NA    NA    NA        
6 Afghanistan AFG     2000 female 0-4   AFG   AFG   NA    NA    NA
```

where pop is a dataset of population numbers, demog contains birth, death and net migration data, and por and pob represent stocks of migrants in country of residence and birth respectively.

d5 is just a list of the possible combinations I want to check in d3, facilitated by the expand_grid:

```
year0 sex    age   e     
  <int> <chr>  <chr> <list>
1  2010 male   0-4   <NULL>
2  2010 male   05-11 <NULL>
3  2010 male   12-17 <NULL>
4  2010 male   18-59 <NULL>
5  2010 male   60+   <NULL>
6  2010 female 0-4   <NULL>
```

The loop will eventually run over all the rows of d5 to run through all combinations. The years in d5 start at 2010 as we have many NAs throughout the 00's in d3.

cc then produces a vector of countries where all metrics for the given combination provided by the row in d5 are available in d5. In the case of the code above, head(cc) looks like this:

```
[1] "AFG" "ALB" "DZA" "ARM" "AZE" "BHR"
```

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we are missing definitions of `d0`, `d3` and possibly more.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: More hits about asking a good question, that can be answered by others: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. There are several ways to provide data, probably adding the output of `dput(<yourData>)` or `dput(head(<yourData>))` to your question is sufficient. [datapasta](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/index.html) is handy as well.